# if else inside a for loop iterating over a json array with custom exception in else block

Tags: java, arrays, json

```
for(int i =0; i< jarray.length;i ++){
    JsonObject jobj = jarray.getJsonObject(i);
    //i am running a database query here to fetch a record based on a value in  the json object
    //i have my if block here
    if(the condition is true){

    }else{
        throw new CustomException
    }
}
```

My question is, for the first iteration if the IF condition fails it's not iterating over the remaining elements in the array and going to the else block directly, how do I make it iterate over the entire array and go to the else block only if none of the elements satisfy the if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do something like:

```
var conditionSatisfied = false;

for(int i =0; i< jarray.length;i ++){
    JsonObject jobj = jarray.getJsonObject(i);

    if(the condition is true){
       conditionSatisfied = true;
    }
}

if(!conditionSatisfied) {
    // throw error
}
```

You loop over the entire array, if there is any element for which the condition is true then the boolean variable `conditionSatisfied` will be **true**. Otherwise `conditionSatisfied` remains **false**, which means none of the elements satisfy the condition, and then it will throw an error (after the loop has finished).